# Dynamic Programing to solve subset of given sum

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given the following Input

```
10 4 3 5 5 7

Where

10 = Total Score

4 = 4 players

3 = Score by player 1
5 = Score by player 2
5 = Score by player 3
7 = Score by player 4
```

Output should print the index of players who's score equal to 10. So for given above output it should print 1 4 or 2 3  because player 1 + player 4 score adds up to 10 and so does the scores by player 2 and player 3. I do not need to PRINT BOTH or ALL combinations. I just want to print any one combination that works.

```
For INPUT : 8 3 2 2 4 OUPUT : 1 2 3 since scores of player 1 player 2 and player 3 equal the total score of 8
```

So i have been reading Dynamic programing tutorials and videos for past week and also got help on stack overflow to fix my initial code.

Following is what i have so far

```
    public boolean findSolution(int[] scores, int total) {
    int W = total;
    int players = scores.length;

    boolean[][] myArray = new boolean[players + 1][total + 1];

    for (int player = 0; player <= players; player++) {
        myArray[player][0] = true;
    }
    for (int score = 1; score < total; score++) {
        myArray[0][score] = false;
    }
    for (int player = 1; player <= players; player++) {
        for (int score = 1; score <= total; score++) {
            myArray[player][score] = myArray[player - 1][score];
            if (score >= scores[player - 1]) {
                myArray[player][score] = myArray[player - 1][score
                        - scores[player - 1]]
                        || myArray[player][score];
            }
        }
    }
    return myArray[players][W];

}
```

This logic creates 2d array and does exhaustive search to see if the combination for a given total is possible and will return true if it is and false if it is not. Now i am having trouble printing the indexes of the players that make it true. So would highly appreciate if someone can help me print the index of a set of players who's score equals the total. I dont NEED TO PRINT all combinations.

Also please ask any question if you don't understand as i am not native English speaker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Programing approach for a subset sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867558/dynamic-programing-approach-for-a-subset-sum)

Comment: @erip yes duplicate but question is slightly different i am stuck on different part now if that makes sense. sorry otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after you have created and updated boolean array `myArray`.

We will iterate from the last player to the first player, checking if we can use the current player in our final result

```
int currentScore = total;//Maintain the current score.
for(int i = lastPlayer ; i >= 0; i--){

}
```

Inside the for loop, to check if this current `i` player is belong to our final set of player, we need to check if there exists a solution for `currentScore - score of i player`

```
if (currentScore >= scores[i] && (i == 0 || myArray[i - 1][currentScore - scores[i]]) {
      //Update current score      
      currentScore -= scores[i];
      //Print name of the player.
      System.out.println("Player " + i);              
}
```